# Resize images without retaining the original aspect ratio using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick, minimagick

I am using CarrierWave to add versions to my uploaded images. resize_to_fit is resizing the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio.How can I resize my images without retaining the original aspect ratio nor croping them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define custom processing method in uploader using Carrierwave's `manipulate!` method. Here's an example I have just tested:

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    storage :file
    process :force_resize => [160, 160]

    def force_resize(width, height)
        manipulate! do |img|
            img.resize("#{width}x#{height}!")
            img
        end
    end
end
```

This resizes images to 160x160px without caring for aspect ratio (note the exclamation mark at the end of argument to `resize`).